# How can i delete a directory in localappdata in the current user

Tags: c#, .net

```cs
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\MyFolder");

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true); 
}
```

Im using this code to delete a directory in %localappdata% in the current used user. But it says that the folder does not exist. I cant figure how to write the path.

Thank you

Comment: I tried using "Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
" as a user suggested form another post but im in a user called "Andrew" my secondary user but the output of that code returns my main user.

Comment: User "Andrew is running the code but the output is my main user called "Its Me" i dont know why this happens :D im gonna try it on another computer or a VM i guess/

Comment: My os is Windows 11 insider build maybe thats the problem ? We will see because im installing the compiler on a Windows 7 Virtual Machine.

Comment: Via the task manager "Andrew" is running all processes, my main user is not even in the list. I am thinking that this is a Windows 11 insider bug.

Comment: It should be a problem with Windows 11 build because in Windows 7 it Works Normally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
string path;
path = @"%LOCALAPPDATA%";
path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);
```

You can refer to the following link for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that: `"C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\MyFolder"` expands into `"C:\Users\C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\MyFolder"`.

You should be doing `"%userprofile%\AppData\Local\MyFolder"`.

This is where basic debugging skills like breakpoints and examining error messages can save you a lot of trouble. The debugger would no doubt be telling you which directory it says doesn't exist.

Even just copy pasting your intended path into Explorer reveals the problem.